# How can I count the number of nodes submitted by the current user?

Tags: nodes, users

I want to expose in a block the number of content type published by the current user.
I know we can write a query, but is there any other method to do it?

Answer (score 3):

You can use the Views module to do this.

1. Create a new view
2. Remove sort options, fields and other default settings
3. Add a field for "Content: Type"
4. Expand the "advanced" part on the right and set "Use aggregation" to "Yes"
5. Add yet another field for "Content: Type"
6. On the second "Content: Type" field, click "Aggregation settings"
7. Set the aggregation type to "count"
8. The second "Content: Type" should now look like "COUNT(Content: Type)"

THIS IS NOT MY SOLUTION LOOK HERE: [Count of nodes by type](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/15871/count-of-nodes-by-type)

Answer (score 1):

The two ways that come to mind are to write a custom query as you suggest, or use the [Views module](http://drupal.org/project/views) to create a block with the content you need.

Views essentially provides a UI for creating custom queries that you can then automatically add to a block/full page/etc.

Depending on your level of PHP/MySQL experience it may actually be easier to write the query yourself...Views has a fair bit of a learning curve although there are a lot of tutorials out there if you search on Google.