# Problem with getting number of nodes created by a user in a View

Tags: 7, views, nodes

I know this question is already asked, here is a few links [How to count the node a user has created in a View?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/52996/how-to-count-the-node-a-user-has-created-in-a-view) or [How can I count the number of nodes submitted by the current user?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/14433/how-can-i-count-the-number-of-nodes-submitted-by-the-current-user)

This is a very simple task but I am facing a problem. 
I'm trying to get the number of nodes of a certain content type created by a user. This is the configuration of the view:

1. setting **Author uid** as contextual filter
2. setting the content type in filter criteria and selecting Node ID as field
3. setting aggregation to `yes` and set the `nid` to use the `Count Distinct` aggregation
4. Setting the `Pager` to *Display all items*

If I don't use the aggregation this is the result:

2158
2151
2152
2153
2154
2155
2156
2157
2142
2143
2144
2145
2146
2147
2148
2149
2150
2141
2140
2139
2138
2137
2136
2127
2126
2125
2124
2123
2128
2129
2130
2131
2132
2133
2134
2135
2122

But if I use it, the result is :

```
8
15
14
```

which 8+15+14 = 37 and number of the nodes is also `37` but I wonder why it displays the 37 this way?

Comment: It's not clear what the problem is. Are you wanting to display only the *total nodes created* or *total nodes created for each type*? What are you expecting it to display by aggregating via counting distinct NIDs?

Comment: I need to count number of nodes of a certain content type created by a user. I will use nid field, as I said, and use aggregation count distinct

Comment: It looks like each row is giving you the count for each node type (e.g. 8 for node type a, 15 for node type b, etc.). Are you expecting it to just return the count of 37?

Comment: There is only one node type. They are all of type `CONTENT_TYPE_A`

Comment: Anything set in the sorting area?

Comment: @StefanKorn post date (desc)

Comment: @StefanKorn very good point, I removed the sort criteria and it worked. Please post this point as answer then I will accept it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make sure that you have no sort criteria set in your view that splits your aggregation.